# close modal and show message on main page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a modal that I want to show a success message after it is closed. My issue is controlling the message on the main view from the modal view. How do I show the message(messageSuccess) on the other view after it closes?

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/IrIt4G7HzAoi4uh7euVu?p=preview

Modal controller: this closes the modal (but how do I show the message on the other view after it closes?)

```
  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    $scope.messageSuccessText = 'Saved!';
    $scope.messageSuccess = true;
  };
```

HTML on main view:

```
<div class="alert alert-success text-center" data-ng-show="messageSuccess">{{messageSuccessText}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Modal has an isolated scope so you need to use the close method to pass data:

Modal Ctrl:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
  $modalInstance.close({item: $scope.selected.item, message: 'Saved!'});
};
```

Parent Ctrl:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
  $scope.selected = result.item;
  $scope.messageSuccessText = result.message;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Parent Html:

```
<div class="alert alert-success text-center" data-ng-show="messageSuccessText">{{messageSuccessText}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just pass your message back in the `close` function.

```
$modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item, 'Saved!', true);
```

Then in your controller you would have code that would look something similar to this:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(item, message, success) {
    $scope.messageSuccess = message;
    $scope.messageSuccessText = success;
}, function() {
    // Dismiss function called instead.
});
```

Comment: You might have to put everything into a single object before passing it. The docs aren't very clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the modal with an object that holds all the data that you need from it. In this case *messageSuccessText*, the handler for closing the modal dialog will look like this:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    var modalData = {
      selectedItem: $scope.selected.item,
      messageSuccess: true,
      messageSuccessText: 'Saved!'
    };
    $modalInstance.close(modalData);
};
```

and in the controller where the modal dialog is opened:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (modalData) {
    $scope.selected = modalData.selectedItem;
    $scope.messageSuccess = modalData.messageSuccess;
    $scope.messageSuccessText =  modalData.messageSuccessText;
}, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Here is your updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O5jfAjq9LAEqBlMd8YAJ?p=preview).